# Intellisense and Xamarin.Forms problems

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I have a problem on a Xamarin.Forms solution on Visual Studio 2019 (and 2017):

I seem to have lost any Intellisense on the solution. If I try to navigate to an object, i get the message "cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret", even for something declared in the same project. I don't have any colors, nr autocompletion.
I've tried to clean, delete obj and bin folder, rebuild, remove .vs folder, reset user data, reinstall VS.... no change...

BUT, If I remove the package Xamarin.Forms, it fixes it ! The problem is that if I reinstall it and restart VS, it comes back...

For information, the solution build and works without any problem.

That solution didn't have any problem previously, it appeared lately, and I can't figure out what caused it.

The version of Forms used is 2.5.1.444934, but I tried to update without succes.

I don't know what to do anymore...

Edit : I'm adding 2 captures on the same code, one with Forms added as a nuget package, and one without.

The various objects are all declared in the same project, same namespace as AffaireSync. 
Without Forms, they are recognised (and DependencyService isn't, but that's normal as it's in Forms).
And With Forms, everything is white, nothing is recognise, nothing is colored, nothing is underlined red...

[Without Android Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UyTf.png)

[With Android Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKRzY.png)

Comment: You should firstly update the IDE to VS 2019 . And the version of Xamarin.Forms will update to the newest at the same time.

Comment: The problem initially arrived on VS 2017, but I've since updated to VS2019, I had the last update yesterday, without any change to my problem unfortunately.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I do not think it's mandatory to update the ide to 17, From what I see opening the XAML as a Source Code Edit should solve his problem, a.reure, Try right-clicking the XAML and opening it as `Source Code Editor`, That should solve your `IntelliSense` issue with regards to your other issue with the Xamarin.Forms package i would suggest you provide more informaiton

Comment: My problem isn't about xaml, but c#. Well xaml too, but that's not my main concern.

Comment: @a.reure You might wanna repair your VS, in case if there were any discrepancies it will resolve those all by itself. Have you already tried it out?

Comment: I'll try that. But since I had the problem on vs 17 and now on VS 2019... And I have other projects (asp.net, not xamarin) that works, I think it's a problem on the project more than the IDE.

Comment: I personally do not think that I feel its the Xamarin SDK that is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I deleted tried a few revert on my solution sources and it didn't fix my problem.

So I deleted my local solutions, checked it out again, and it's all fixed... I can't figured out what happen, but it works, so I'm not touching anything...